# CustomErrors only catches explicit page links

Tags: asp.net, iis, custom-errors

I have custom errors turned on and when I go to

`www.mywebsite.com/video/default.aspx` it shows error which corresponds to 404 and this is fine

but when I go to `www.mywebsite.com/video/` it shows a generic iis 404 error.

My other pages that have files work fine like 
`www.mywebsite.com/photo/` would redirect to `www.mywebsite.com/photo/default.aspx` because files exists and default is setup in IIS.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your <customErrors></customErrors> tag and what version of ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: What version of iis are you using?

Comment: IIS 6

<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/errors/GeneralError.aspx">
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/errors/PageNotFound.aspx" />
</customErrors>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 404 handler specified in the web.config only works for files handled by the ASP.NET runtime. This is why it is working for `www.mywebsite.com/video/default.aspx` and not `www.mywebsite.com/video/`, the generic error your observing is the one configured by default in IIS. You will need to go into IIS Manager and set 404's to be redirected to your `PageNotFound.aspx`.

[Here's](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/80cb8d8d-8fd8-4af5-bb3b-4d11fff3ab9c.mspx?mfr=true) some more infomtion on configuring custom error messages in IIS 6.0.